# How to Pass Data between Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments

For all those who are downvoting and voting for this question to be closed thinking it has something to do with the scope of textview.....then have a look,it has nothing to do with the scope of textview

Unable to pass data between fragments,the app crashes,i don't know what i am doing wrong...i followed this link
http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-passing-data-between-fragments/

here is the code i am using
Fragment A(this fragment is passing the data)

```
public class FragmentSongs extends  Fragment implements Serializable,OnFragmentCreatedListener {
ListView SngList;


 ArrayList<SongDetails> Songinfo=null;
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_song, null);

    SngList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.SongList);
    registerForContextMenu(SngList);
    //File f=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Music");
    File f=new File("/system/");
    int j=0;int i=0;

    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

      Songinfo = getSongsFromDirectory(f);



    //sorting done below
    if (Songinfo.size()>0)
    {

        for( j=0; j<Songinfo.size();j++)
        {
            for ( i=j+1 ; i<Songinfo.size(); i++)
            { 
                SongDetails a=Songinfo.get(i);
                SongDetails b=Songinfo.get(j);
                if(a.getSong().toLowerCase().compareTo(b.getSong().toLowerCase())<0)
                {   

                    Songinfo.set(i,b );
                    Songinfo.set(j,a);
                }
            }

        }






   SngList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(Songinfo));
   return view;
    }
    else return null;

}
OnFragmentCreatedListener listener;
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        listener = (OnFragmentCreatedListener) getActivity();
        listener.onFragmentCreated(Songinfo);
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onFragmentCreated");
    }
}
```

fragment B(the receiver fragment )

```
    public class FragmentArtists extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<SongDetails> songinfo2;
ViewGroup view;
int s=5;//TextView text;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{Context context;
LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();   

    view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_artist,  null);
// view =  lf.inflate(R.layout.test,container, false);
// view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test,container, false);


 s=s+5;
//     text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tt);when i use this,it works fine but i want to do it in the other method

//text.setText("makzzz");when i use this,it works fine but i want to do it in the other method
return view;

}

 void setSongList(ArrayList<SongDetails> songinfo) 
{    //TextView text=(TextView)this.getView().findViewById(R.id.tt);//when i used this view was not global
      TextView text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tt);//when i used this,view was global;
      //TextView text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tt);
    // text=(TextView)super.getView().findViewById(R.id.tt);


     text.setText("makzzz");
```

the method in holder activity (this activity holds the fragments)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mymusic);


           fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentSongs.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentArtists.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentPlaylists.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentAlbums.class.getName())); 


            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);


            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);



            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
            pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

            pager.setCurrentItem(0);

    }      public void onFragmentCreated(ArrayList<SongDetails> msg) {
            FragmentArtists Obj=(FragmentArtists)  fragments.get(1);
            Obj.setSongList(msg);
            }

    }
```

the callback class:

```
package sourcecode.jazzplayer;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public interface OnFragmentCreatedListener {
    public void onFragmentCreated(ArrayList<SongDetails> msg);

}
```

here is the logcat

```
  09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at sourcecode.jazzplayer.FragmentArtists.setSongList(FragmentArtists.java:55)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at sourcecode.jazzplayer.MyMusic.onFragmentCreated(MyMusic.java:45)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at sourcecode.jazzplayer.FragmentSongs.onAttach(FragmentSongs.java:128)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:883)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:823)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:819)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1066)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2072)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1044)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-19 23:50:46.851: E/AndroidRuntime(2125):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

the error is in this line of code

TextView text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tt);
//this line is in the receiver fragment (fragmentArtist)

Comment: We can perhaps help if we know what the crash is. Can you post the logcat?

Comment: Post the logcat... But i think you should use another way to pass data between fragment (widh argument for example)

Comment: @Pauland please give me the link ,of the other way of passing the data

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava Sorry, if you create your fragment by XML, is the good way...
For your problem, can you post your xml layout for the activity ?

Comment: @Pauland i didn't get you??did you mean that have if i set up individual  layout for the the fragments or not?then yes i have

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava post all your activity code please...

Comment: @andy256 i have posted the logcat

Comment: The exception is pretty clear. When the `FragmentSongs` is attached to the activity(requested by the `ViewPager` where it will appear) its `onAttach` method is called. In this method you cast the `Activity` to your listener **but you also call immediately the listener's callback**. This will make your app crash because in that listener you're trying to work with the view of the second fragment of the `ViewPager`, `FragmentArtists`. This fragment hasn't gone through it's lifecycle callbacks so there isn't a view for it yet(so no `TextView` on which to set data).

Comment: So remove the line `listener.onFragmentCreated(Songinfo);` from the `FragmentSongs`' `onAttach()` method and follow a better tutorial.

Comment: everywhere even on this site,it has been done the way i am dong...anyways please can u provide me with a better example?

Comment: and i am creating all the fragments together...by pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

Comment: Did you do what I said above?

Comment: you asked me to follow a better tutorial,and if i remove the line which you pointed to,how will i pass the data??

Comment: and this tutorial has also been used in the androiddevelopment docs

Comment: From what I can see, the exception does not relate to the question title at all. To see that you are indeed receiving the data, place a log statement inside `FragmentArtists#setSongList()`: `Log.d("TEST", "Received list with " + songInfo.size() + " items.");`.

Comment: i did what you said....now the app crashes with null point exception at Log.d("TEST", "Received list with " + songinfo.size() + " items.")

Comment: i tried removing the songInfo.size() from the statement,so that the log just prints a line....but it didn't ..seems like the method is not being executed at all

Comment: @user2558882 i made a few changes in the code and now the message is being received,but still i cannot display it in a textview...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already said in my comment you're trying to work with a `Fragment` when it's not properly initialized yet. When the `FragmentSongs` is attached to the `Activity`(action requested by the `ViewPager` where it will appear) its `onAttach()` method is called. In this method you cast the `Activity` to your listener, **but you also call immediately the listener's callback**. This will make your app crash(with the exception you posted) because in that listener you're trying to work with the view of the second `Fragment` of the `ViewPager`, `FragmentArtists`. This `Fragment` isn't yet initialized, at this moment the first fragment of the `ViewPager` is barely being attached to the activity and you're already trying to work with the view of the second fragment which will obviously fail.

The tutorial you linked to is ok, simplistic, but ok(without going to that link I assumed your code is from the tutorial). The problem is that you used that code from a very simplistic scenario  in a more complex situation(in fact if you insert your current code in that tutorial's code you'll get the same exception(calling the listener too early)).

That callback listener interface should be used while the fragment is fully built(like when the user is using the app and selects a song and you want to show to him the artist part of the app(at that moment call the listener and make it pass data)) also carefully handling the possibility of a fragment not being available.

If you need to pass data between fragments so early in the fragment's lifecycle that you can't guarantee the fragment is yet available(like you do with calling the listener in `onAttach()` of a fragment) then implement the fragment to get the data **directly** from the activity when it's built, in one of its lifecycle methods. What you're passing it's not clear so there isn't much I can say here.

Comment: i have a question for you...... pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);(this code is in the holder activity where i have defined my fragments)
doesn't this line of code ensures that my fragments will be built all at the same time...???

Comment: and if it doesn't can we use view pager to create more than one fragments,all at the same time ?and once they are created,then only display them?

Comment: and the tutorial which i followed is also given in the developer website

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava `setOffScreenPageLimit()` will keep the fragment instances after they are built(and you should use this method with care). The fragments views aren't built yet when the `onAttach` method is called and  you're already trying to access the view of another fragment(which also isn't initialized). There isn't any sample on the developer site that you can show me where they are calling the listener modifying the view of another fragment directly from the `onAttach()` method of another fragment. Edit your question and explain what you're trying to pass between the fragments.

Comment: ok thank you for explaining me the setoffscreen.. part that was the main confusion in my mind which u just answered 

but the thing u are saying about onAttach() i have a dboubt
here have a look,http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html
..i know what u are trying to say....(in the tutorial they haven't written the code on how they have initialized the fragments,but they did use OnAttach() the same way i did..maybe thats the reason why i got confused)

Comment: and i still don't know how i can study the life cycle of more than one fragments attached with each other??so that this issue won't arise....,and will the onStart() method solve the problem instead of onAttach()?

Comment: or if u can answer how can i ensure that the other fragment has been created ??

Comment: i think i have got the basic idea +1 for your explanation ,however i will only accept your answer and give you the bounty when i solve this problem....if i am unable to solve it within 7 days i will give u the bounty but won't accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Your `FragmentSongs` class needs to implement `OnFragmentCreatedListener`

```
public class FragmentSongs extends Fragment implements OnFragmentCreatedListener { 

  public void onFragmentCreated(ArrayList<SongDetails> msg) {
    // whatever
  }


}
```

---

or in `onAttach` of your 'Fragment A':

```
        listener =  (OnFragmentCreatedListener) activity;
```

this would mean your `Activity` needs to implement `OnFragmentCreatedListener`

Comment: that in turn gives me another (NullPointException)error...........in fragment B...in the method (which is meant to set something after receiving  info from the other fragment)and the error is  in this line
text.setText("makzzz");

Comment: well yes, so I answered your question. Now one of your views is null (another separate question).

Comment: well,i will give the bounty to u if i solve that problem,(as that may lead to another problem related to this one)

Comment: because as what i remember,i had tried implementing it(what u just told) a few days ago and i was stuck somehwhere......if i am unable to  solve the problem within 7 days,i will give u the bounty,but won't check ur answer as correct..

Comment: you don't give enough code for me to do your homework for you sorry

Comment: i am stuck with the problem....the method which is receiving the data seems like its not being executed at all