# Unable to pass data between fragments.....TextView throws NullPoint Exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

For all those who are downvoting and voting for this question to be closed thinking it has something to do with the scope of textview.....then have a look,it has nothing to do with the scope of textview.

```
public class FragmentArtists extends Fragment {
        ArrayList<SongDetails> songinfo2;
    View view;
    TextView text;
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {Context context;
    LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();   

    //view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_artist,  null);
 view =  lf.inflate(R.layout.test,container, false);
// view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test,container, false);


     //     text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tt);when i use this,it works fine but i want to do it in the other method

//text.setText("makzzz");when i use this,it works fine but i want to do it in the other method
return view;

}

 void setSongList(ArrayList<SongDetails> songinfo) 
{    //TextView text=(TextView)this.getView().findViewById(R.id.tt);//when i used this view was not global
      text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tt);//when i used this,view was global;
      //TextView text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tt);
    // text=(TextView)super.getView().findViewById(R.id.tt);
    //i also tried keeping the "text" local     

     text.setText("makzzz");
}}
```

the fragment which is sending the data ..........

```
public class FragmentSongs extends  Fragment implements Serializable {

    ListView SngList;


     ArrayList<SongDetails> Songinfo=null;
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {

        ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_song, null);

        SngList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.SongList);
        registerForContextMenu(SngList);
        //File f=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/Music");
        File f=new File("/system/");
        int j=0;int i=0;

        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

          Songinfo = getSongsFromDirectory(f);



        //sorting done below
        if (Songinfo.size()>0)
        {

            for( j=0; j<Songinfo.size();j++)
            {
                for ( i=j+1 ; i<Songinfo.size(); i++)
                { 
                    SongDetails a=Songinfo.get(i);
                    SongDetails b=Songinfo.get(j);
                    if(a.getSong().toLowerCase().compareTo(b.getSong().toLowerCase())<0)
                    {   

                        Songinfo.set(i,b );
                        Songinfo.set(j,a);
                    }
                }

            }






       SngList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(Songinfo));
       return view;
        }
        else return null;

    }
    OnFragmentCreatedListener listener;
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            listener = (OnFragmentCreatedListener) getActivity();
            listener.onFragmentCreated(Songinfo);
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement onFragmentCreated");
        }
    }
```

.
.
.
.
.

the holder activity

```
package sourcecode.jazzplayer;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import sourcecode.jazzplayer.FragmentSongs.OnFragmentCreatedListener;
import sourcecode.jazzplayer.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MyMusic  extends FragmentActivity implements OnFragmentCreatedListener{
    List<Fragment> fragments;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mymusic);


           fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentSongs.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentArtists.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentPlaylists.class.getName()));
            fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentAlbums.class.getName())); 


            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);


            ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);



            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
            pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

            pager.setCurrentItem(0);

    }    @Override 
         public void onFragmentCreated(ArrayList<SongDetails> msg) {
            FragmentArtists Obj=(FragmentArtists)  fragments.get(1);
            Obj.setSongList(msg);
            }

    }
```

Comment: where do you call `setSongList`? you can initialize `onCreateView`. Declare textview as a class member and use it in `setSongList`

Comment: in the holderactivity of the fragment,as i am passing data between fragments

Comment: this is the code if u need it..........http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632402/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments

Comment: i have tried setting textview as a class member ,please go through my code....i have written all the alternatives that i have tried

Comment: http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html   will provide you with some basic info that might help you answer your own problem

Comment: @petey are u suggesting that i should use a global variable??

Comment: if you're calling `setSongList` before `onCreateView` is called, then no wonder the crash

Comment: I agree with @gunar. this could be your problem

Comment: for all those who downvoted,please only downvote if u think u know the correct soultion and think this question is too stupid  to be asked

Comment: @gunar well i followed this link..and there too he does the same

http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-passing-data-between-fragments/

Comment: @AnkitSrivastava: the author of that article is passing the string after both `onCreateView` have been called. Look at how he does that in combination with `onAttach`

Comment: @gunar i have done all that...i have updated my question with the code...

Comment: @gunar please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call

```
text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tt);
```

onCreateView(), or in the method that is called from onCreateView() before doing anything with it. If text hasn't been assigned to UI element, TextView throws NullPoint Exception. If you really want that assigning in another method, write a method like

```
private void initUI()
```

Comment: i followed this link

here too he does the same(as what i did)
http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-passing-data-between-fragments/

Comment: It won't give error of course if you do it before manupulating it but I was suggesting it as it would be best practice to initialize UI element first in a method.

Comment: please elaborate..and i already tried setting up the UI elements(Textview,view) as globals

Comment: I'll try that example also. Did you did anything different from that example

Comment: yes....in the e.g he is sending the message(inside layout one) through  a click event  but i passing it from onAttach (inside "fragment which is sending the data")