# How to make sure that the view of the other attached fragments has been created?

Tags: android, android-fragments

hello i need to pass information between 2 fragments (from fragment A to framgnet B) and i am unable to...i followed the tutorial given in the developers website,but somehow i am getting errors...
i was getting a null  point exception in the textview inside fragment B...i made sure that there was no problem with the scope of the textview and all guys could help me was that maybe i am passing the information from fragment a to b and demanding it to be displayed in b when the view of b has yet not been created..
so i want to know how i can make sure that the view of the other fragment has been created or not?
but my main problem still remains how i can pass data between fragments???
i asked two questions related to this 
[Unable to pass data between fragments.....TextView throws NullPoint Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896941/unable-to-pass-data-between-fragments-textview-throws-nullpoint-exception)
and 
[How to Pass Data between Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18632402/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments)

i followed the e.g given in dev website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not cache your view. Use getView() method to get your root view. It will be created, if alredy not.

Change your line:

```
TextView text=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tt);
```

To:

```
TextView text=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tt);
```

And anyway, setting value to view directly from external object is not good way.
You can do something like this:

```
private String mText = null;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // onActivityCreated calls after view creation, and attaching fragment to Activity so it's good place to fill your views with default info
    TextView text=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tt);
    text.setText(mText);
}

void setSongList(ArrayList<SongDetails> songinfo) {
    View v = getView();

    // Cache your text, and set it to TextView  only if View already created.
    this.mText = "mytext";
    if(v != null) {
        TextView text=(TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.tt);
        text.setText(mText);
    }
}
```

Comment: did that.still same error

Comment: Look at my updated answer.

Comment: well there was another problem which was causing the error and i have solved it,not this one.But anyways thanx for trying and helping me out...+1 for that and i am acccepting your answer....